# Update control label from thread in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, winforms, webforms

```
delegate void SetTextCallback( string text );    

private void UpdateControl( string text ) {
        if ( this.myLabel.InvokeRequired ) {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback( UpdateControl );
            this.Invoke( d, new object[] { text } );
        }
        else {
            this.myLabel.Text = text;
        }
}
```

I have a **WinForm** application and in this application, I used threads to access UI controls and update them.

Now, I want to convert this code to **ASP.NET Web Forms** but `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` methods are unavailable for **Web Forms**.

What is the equivelant of `Invoke`, `InvokeRequired` methods in **Web Forms** or How can i achieve and update an UI control in **ASP.NET Web Forms**

Scenario that I use this `UpdateControl` is that I will post some files to a folder. These labels will show what's happening now, Which file is sending now, and Which database is updating now.

Comment: `WinForms` and `WebForms` UI are totally different worlds and when rewriting UI in other framework you should design UI based on concepts of that framewrok and not only look for equivalents. Maybe the equivalent of that task in a web application could be changing the UI in client using client javascript for example in a timer or after success of an ajax call or after some events. Or somehow you may compare that task with using Ajax Control Toolkit to change UI.

Comment: What's the scenario that you use such `UdateControl` method?

Comment: Scenario is that I will post some files to a folder. These labels will show what's happening now? Which file is sending now? Which database is updating now?

Comment: Answer may be helpful I don't know but I gotta use multithreading

Comment: Multi-threading in UI of a Web Application means using JavaScript and ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WinForms` and `WebForms` UI are totally different worlds and when rewriting UI in other framework you should design UI based on concepts of that framework and not only look for equivalents.

It seems you need to use **javascript**, libraries like **jQuery** and concepts like **ajax** to gain what you had in a Windows Forms application.

An equivalent for such tasks in a web application could be changing the UI in client using **javascript**, for example in a timer or after success of an **ajax** call or after some other events.

Also if you are using `WbForms` somehow you may compare such tasks with using **UpdatePanel** or using **Ajax Control Toolkit** to change UI.

For that specific task, uploading files in Webforms, you can take a look at [`AjaxFileUpload`](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx).